# Refactor XML View ID in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, intellij-idea, refactoring

I noticed I lacked inspiration when first naming the IDs for some of the views in my XML layouts, and now I want to change their name. For instace, I want to **rename "image_logo"**..

[image: Bad ID]

to

[image: Good ID]

**"company_logo_light_id"**

And because same layouts are used as ContentViews for multiple activities/fragments, manually changing the ID would result in tons of errors.

I know Android Studio(IntelliJ) provides the feature to refactor at a project level, because I'm sure I did it once before, but I simply can't recall how it was done.

How is it done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it turns out the answer was fairly simple: right click on ID value - refactor - rename
Or simply place cursor on ID attribute and use SHIFT+F6

[image]

Answer (score 1):

`Shift+F6` over the text which you want to change

Answer (score 0):

Click on component Id value, context Menu (right click) -> Refactor -> Rename